# wordpress virtual page subdirectories

Tags: wordpress

I have a wp site that has products as well as other services.
I want the product pages to have the name product-catalogue as part of the url.

Is there a way of having of doing this without having to create a physical subdirectory for these pages.

Could permalinks be an option?

thanks
maggs

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use custom permalink structure 
write the desired structure using %postname% under Settings > permalink > custom permalinks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can create a post type "product-catalogue" then rewrite your url like this.

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Product'
    );
    register_post_type( 'product-catalogue', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();  
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );

function prefix_product_catalogue_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'product-catalogue/([^/]+)/about', 'index.php?product-catalogue=$matches[1]&about=yes', 'top' );

}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_product_catalogue_rewrite_rule' );

// create single.php like template for your custom post type ie, product-catalogue
function prefix_url_rewrite_templates() {

    if ( get_query_var( 'about' ) && is_singular( 'band' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/single-product-catalogue.php';
        });
    }


}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_url_rewrite_templates' );
```

paste this code in your function.php of theme folder.